# Magento Module rewrite

Tags: magento, module, url-rewriting

I have a Magento extension with custom product type that in config.xml use this action:

```
   <routers>

        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>
                    <to>custom-product-module/index</to>
                    <override_actions>true</override_actions>
                    <actions>
                        <view>
                            <to>custom-product-module/index/view</to>
                        </view>
                    </actions>
                </product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>

    </routers>
```

The problem is that this rewrite action affect also all the other product types like simple product, virtual product etc. What I want is to bring Magento to use this rewrite action only for the custom product type used from my extension.

Any help please? best regards